# Как правильно передать параметру значение

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть вот такой код:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template name="line">
    <xsl:param name="data" />
    <xsl:for-each select="//машина">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$data" />
      </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:call-template name="line">
          <xsl:with-param name="data" select="@цвет" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

для такого содержимого хмl:

```
<машина цвет="красный" вес="500"/>
```

я хочу сделать шаблон по которому будет создаваться строка с всеми цветами машин при помощи xslt кода, но он не работает. Насколько я понял я не правильно передаю цвет, но такой код сработал бы не будь он шаблоном.

Comment: Что значит `со всеми цветами`? Приведите минимальный пример входного XML и ожидаемого выходного HTML

Comment: Суть в том что тут 
**<xsl:for-each select="//машина">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$data" />
      </td>
    </xsl:for-each>**
из всех машин  он ищет то что я ему передаю а передаю я ему "@цвет" вот в этой строчке   **<xsl:with-param name="data" select="@цвет" />** по сути я хочу что бы я передал в template атрибут " цвет" или " вес" и он вывел их  все по порядку

Comment: Что тут? Расскажите, чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Я хочу передать в template  имя аргумента например "цвет" ,что бы template вывел мне все значение  аргумента для всех "машин" . По итогу он должен будет вывести в строку цвета всех машин

Comment: Такой вот хml:
**<машина цвет="красный" вес="500"/>
<машина цвет="желтый" вес="500"/>
<машина цвет="синий" вес="500"/>
<машина цвет="красный" вес="500"/>
<машина цвет="белый" вес="500"/>
<машина цвет="синий" вес="500"/>**

должен выдавать такой html :
красный желтый синий красный белый синий

Comment: Для редактирования исходного вопроса используйте кнопку [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно извратиться следующим образом. Имя атрибута нужно задавать в одинарных кавычках, чтобы оно трактовалось как текст, а не как имя узла. И без знака `@`, потому что мы будем сравнивать с ним имя узла вручную.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template name="line">
    <xsl:param name="data" />
    <xsl:for-each select="//машина/@*[local-name() = $data]">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </td>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:call-template name="line">
          <xsl:with-param name="data" select="'цвет'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо ) Работает идеально

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код не работает, потому, что вы пытаетесь получить атрибут `цвет` находясь в контексте корневого узла (`<xsl:template match="/">`)

Для вывода цветов всех машин используйте такой код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template name="line">
    <xsl:for-each select="//машина">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@цвет" />
      </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:call-template name="line"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

А еще лучше - разделите обработку элементов на разные шаблоны

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="машина">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@цвет" />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//машина"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ну и напоследок хочу отметить, что оператор `//` не стоит использовать **никогда**. Этот оператор **очень** медленный, т.к. собирает узлы со **всего** документа. Всегда лучше указывать полный путь к элементу. Если же элемент может находиться на произвольном уровне вложенности, то тогда использовать оператор `.//` который вытащит все **дочерние** элементы **текущего** узла

---

**Update**

Если вам нужен шаблон под произвольный атрибут, то можно делать так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="машина/@*">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//машина/@цвет"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//машина/@вес"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Или так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="машина">
    <xsl:param name="attr"/>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = $attr]" />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//машина">
          <!-- Обратите внимание - мы передаем имя атрибута как строку -->
          <xsl:with-param name="attr" select="'цвет'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Спасибо , но это немного не то что нужно. Дело в том что у вас в template сразу указанно ** <xsl:value-of select="@цвет" />**  а моя цель в том что бы не зная заранее ,я сам передавал то что хочу получить.  например я захочу вывести не цвета а вес машин и template уже надо будет переписывать под ** <xsl:value-of select="@вес" />** поэтому я и пытался передать в параметры аргумент а его ежу испоьзовал бы template. Однако большое спасибо за объяснение работы узлов

Comment: @ИгорьБутков Вот я и просил вас четко написать, что вам нужно

Comment: Прошу прощения. У меня в голове это звучало понятнее))

Comment: @ИгорьБутков Я обновил ответ

Comment: А мне первый вариант в апдейте больше всего нравится. Настоящий паттерн-матчинг.